# simple class method not working

Tags: php, function

this is a super basic question but my classes are not working the way I expect them to. I am a CS student in my second year so go easy on me! The only other language I know is Java. Here is my class, called class.Team.php (represents a team).

```
<?php
class Team
{
  private $teamId='';
  private $teamName='Tyler';
  private $teamCity='';
  private $homeField='';
  private $headCoach='';
  private $mascot='';
  private $wins=0;
  private $losses=0;
  private $roster;

  function display(){
    return $teamName;
  }
}
?>
```

So when I call the display() method it should return a string (hardcoded as "tyler). Here is my test script. It is simply displaying nothing. A blank white page. Am I missing something??

```
<?php
include ('class.Team.php');
$um = new Team;
$string = $um->display();
print ($string);
?>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Could you fix your identation?

Comment: Also it is `$this->teamName`. Also the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: no tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski 2 space indentation? eeeew ;)

Comment: btw: class functions are called 'methods', while class variables are called 'members'

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't want to break my spacebar.  (though I started working in a 2-space RoR shop a year ago and I shed tears every day.  I'm a _tab literals have semantic meaning, and your editor should display the desired width_ kind of guy.)

Comment: hehe np. Kudos for fixing the post anyway. And I feel your pain / trauma :D

Comment: @PeeHaa members or properties. some call it attributes but I do not second that. The point is that it should rather not be named variables to avoid disambiguation.

Comment: methods are also members just like properties. true on the disambiguation though

Comment: @BenSwayne The 'homework' tag has been deprecated; please don't use it any longer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `$this` keyword.

```
function display(){
    return $this->teamName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not Java. You have to use `$this` to reference own instance.

```
return $this->teamName;
```